# Grammar check or necessity of because

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I was just wondering if it was necessary to put "Because" in this sentence

Sorry my mother randomly messaged you last night. Because, she couldn't contact me so she decided to message a few people on my friend list.

or is this one better

Sorry my mother randomly messaged you last night because she couldn’t contact me. So, she decided to message a few people on my friend list

Also, if it's not necessary. Would it be wrong to still put it there?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user299363 says, "Because" is not necessary. But if you want to use "because", then you need two clauses: the one coming right after "because", which gives the reason or explanation, and a main clause which says the thing that needed explaining. If you use "because" with the "reason" clause, then the other clause shouldn't have "so".

And you don't put a comma to separate "because" from the following clause.

So you'd have this:

"Sorry my mother randomly messaged you last night. Because she couldn't contact me, she decided to message a few people on my friend list."

Comment: Thank you! was it wrong to put the word "because" then?

Comment: There are a few ways to say what you wanted to say. It's not wrong to put the word "because" before the reason. What's wrong is to put the word "because" before the reason **and** "so" before the thing it's explaining.

Comment: What if I didn't use the word "because" at all and said "Sorry my mother randomly messaged you last night. She couldn't contact me so she decided to message a few people on my friend list" instead.

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Answer (score -1):

"Because", in this case isn't necessary at all.

And I'd say this one sounds better, "Sorry my mother randomly messaged you last night. Because, she couldn't contact me so she decided to message a few people on my friend list."